# Show only 1 map in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am working with Openlayers3. When zoom out same continents are shown twice.

I want to show only 1 map in the screen. Or is there a way to get the maximum extend of one map?

Comment: Can you put the code that creates the layer? I'm not able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wrapX: false on your sources.

Comment: Here is the documentation for wrapX: `Wrap the world horizontally. Default is true. For vector editing across the -180° and 180° meridians to work properly, this should be set to false. The resulting geometry coordinates will then exceed the world bounds.`